# Como enviar variáveis do php para a página html?

Tags: php, html

estou criando uma pagina de testes para ver se consigo usar, aprender e depois passar isso pra um projeto maior.

Meu problema é o seguinte:
crio o formulario de envio no HTML, faço a pesquisa no BD com o PHP, mas nao consigo devolver para o HTML o resultado da pesquisa no PHP

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Teste</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="teste.php ">
        <input type="submit" name="Pesquisar"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','login_sessao');

    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT usu_Senha FROM tb_usuario where usu_Email = 'emailQualquer'");

    $consultaQ = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);
    echo "Sua senha é: " + $consulta['usu_Senha'];
?>
```

Desculpe se estiver formatado errado, primeira vez fazendo uma pergunta, mas agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O operador de concatenação de *strings* no **PHP** é o **ponto**:  `.` !

Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php
$string = 'texto qualquer';

echo 'Este é um ' + $string; // Exibe "0"
echo 'Este é um ' . $string; // Exibe "Este é um texto qualquer"
```

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP - Operadores de String](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php)

Se isso não resolver seu problema, poste a saída da sua consulta (avisos, erros, etc do PHP).

Comment: entendi, e agora pra conseguir enviar essa variavel $string pra pagina html?, tentei colocar no value de uma `<tag>` o seguinte: `value = <?php echo $string; ?>` mas nao foi

Comment: `value="<?php echo $string; ?>"` - corrigindo

Comment: O segundo comentário deveria funcionar. Lembrando que o php, normalmente, é interpretado apenas em páginas com a extensão .php. Salvo casos de configuração para outras extensões...

Comment: este segundo comentário esta dentro de uma pagina html, será que pode ser esse o motivo de não estar retornando nenhum resultado?

Comment: Só mudar e testar, uai. Vai ser na mosca.

Comment: caramba, que erro bobo, consegui resolver agora, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

tudo bom! Seguinte, a diversas formas de você resultar os dados do PHP para o HTML! A forma que é mais simples é criar a consulta no próprio arquivo e depois "desenhar" a tabela recebendo o array que vem do Banco de Dados! Outra maneira seria utilizar consulta pelo metodo ajax. No metodo ajax você dispara a consulta para um link e esse link você retorna ja a tabela montada e aponta para uma DIV.

No codigo abaixo eu utilizo o JavaScript com o Ajax, eu aponto qual é minha variavel
do valor tipo, aponto qual seria minha pagina em php e retorno os dados na div #dados. Dentro do arquivo buscateste.php eu crio a consulta em php com o banco mysql e depois eu crio uma tabela em html mostrando os dados da consulta

```js
function buscaTipo(){

    var valorTipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;
    var page = "buscateste.php";

    if(valorTipo !=''){
      $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: page, beforeSend: function(){
          $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
        },
        data: {valorTipo: valorTipo,
          opcao: 1},
        success: function(msg)
        {
          $("#dados").html(msg);
        }
      })
    }else{
      $.post('buscateste.php', function(retorna){
        $("#dados").html(retorna);
    });

}}
```